# How To Speed Up Transfer Rate of Images Captured By Camera And Sent Using Python Sockets Over Mesh Network

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi3, mesh-network

I am capturing an image from one Pi 3 using the standard `PiCamera` python bindings.

I then send this image to another Pi 3 over a WiFi mesh network created using [batman-adv](https://www.open-mesh.org/projects/batman-adv/wiki/Quick-start-guide#Simple-mesh-network)

The code I've found for the socket part, sends the image len firstly, then sends the actual Byte stream.

This results in exactly 20 images in 10 seconds, i.e. 2 frames per second,  which is a terrible frame rate.

I am confident that if I can skip the "handshake" so to speak then I can increase the capture rate, but how can I save/process an image without knowing the content length?

I tried decreasing the resolution of the image by half but that didn't result in any improvement.

I also printed out the image len of one attempt and then used the max to statically read bytes on the next run, but that resulted in un-viewable images; presumably because I read beyond one image so each file was more/less than actual image.

The below code is for the `client.py`

```
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import picamera

client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(('192.168.123.3', 6666))
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')

try:
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (640, 480)
        # Start a preview and let the camera warm up for 2 seconds
        camera.start_preview()
        time.sleep(2)

        # Note the start time and construct a stream to hold image data
        # temporarily (we could write it directly to connection but in this
        # case we want to find out the size of each capture first to keep
        # our protocol simple)
        start = time.time()
        stream = io.BytesIO()

        for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream, 'jpeg'):
            # Write the length of the capture to the stream and flush to
            # ensure it actually gets sent
            connection.write(struct.pack('<L', stream.tell()))
            connection.flush()

            # Rewind the stream and send the image data over the wire
            stream.seek(0)
            connection.write(stream.read())

            # If we've been capturing for more than 10 seconds, quit
            if time.time() - start > 10:
                break

            # Reset the stream for the next capture
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()

    # Write a length of zero to the stream to signal we're done
    connection.write(struct.pack('<L', 0))
finally:
    connection.close()
    client_socket.close()
```

The code for `server.py`

```
import io
import socket
import struct
from PIL import Image

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('192.168.123.3', 6666))
server_socket.listen(0)
imagecounter = 1

connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rb')

try:
    while True:
        # Read the length of the image as a 32-bit unsigned int. If the
        # length is zero, quit the loop
        image_len = struct.unpack('<L', connection.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]

        if not image_len:
            break

        # Construct a stream to hold the image data and read the image
        # data from the connection
        image_stream = io.BytesIO()
        image_stream.write(connection.read(image_len))

        # Rewind the stream, save it as a file
        image_stream.seek(0)
        with open('image%s.jpg' % imagecounter, 'wb') as img:
            img.write(image_stream.read())

        imagecounter += 1

finally:
    connection.close()
    server_socket.close()
```

The `mesh` / `ad-hoc` network is a hard requirement.  I'd like to use it and the reasons are beyond the scope of this question.

I am wondering:

1. How can I cut out the image len handshake and still be able to save/process the image correctly
2. Is there a better approach to speeding up this transfer?

My target is 10 to 15 images per second, or more if possible.

Comment: why not compress the data first with gz or similar?

Comment: that's true! I can't believe I didn't think of that!

Comment: @dangee1705 do you have an example of sending a compressed byte stream over a socket

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you compress the data first before sending it. You could do this with the `zlib` module. For example:

```
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import picamera
import zlib # need this for compression

client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(('192.168.123.3', 6666))
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')

try:
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (640, 480)
        # Start a preview and let the camera warm up for 2 seconds
        camera.start_preview()
        time.sleep(2)

        # Note the start time and construct a stream to hold image data
        # temporarily (we could write it directly to connection but in this
        # case we want to find out the size of each capture first to keep
        # our protocol simple)
        start = time.time()
        stream = io.BytesIO()

        for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream, 'jpeg'):

            data = zlib.compress(stream.read())

            # Write the length of the capture to the stream and flush to
            # ensure it actually gets sent
            connection.write(struct.pack('<L', len(data))
            connection.flush()

            # Rewind the stream and send the image data over the wire
            stream.seek(0)
            connection.write(data)

            # If we've been capturing for more than 10 seconds, quit
            if time.time() - start > 10:
                break

            # Reset the stream for the next capture
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()

    # Write a length of zero to the stream to signal we're done
    connection.write(struct.pack('<L', 0))
finally:
    connection.close()
    client_socket.close()
```

You'll also have to decompress on the other side

```
import io
import socket
import struct
from PIL import Image
import zlib

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('192.168.123.3', 6666))
server_socket.listen(0)
imagecounter = 1

connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rb')

try:
    while True:
        # Read the length of the image as a 32-bit unsigned int. If the
        # length is zero, quit the loop
        image_len = struct.unpack('<L', connection.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]

        if not image_len:
            break

        # Construct a stream to hold the image data and read the image
        # data from the connection
        image_stream = io.BytesIO()
        image_stream.write(connection.read(image_len))

        # Rewind the stream, save it as a file
        image_stream.seek(0)
        with open('image%s.jpg' % imagecounter, 'wb') as img:
            img.write(zlib.decompress(image_stream.read()))

        imagecounter += 1

finally:
    connection.close()
    server_socket.close()
```

Hopefully that should work!

Comment: Thanks dangee1705!  I will try it and report here shortly